# Trinitarian Ontology... What is it? Being vs person vs essence vs _______

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, tetragrammaton

I will try to ask this unique question again.  How can we answer here without defining simple words used to define God?

**Premise**

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology)

> ***Ontology*** addresses questions of how entities are grouped into categories and which of these entities exist on the most fundamental level. Ontologists often try to determine what the categories or highest kinds are and how they form a system of categories that encompasses classification of all entities.

**person**
pûr′sən
noun

> An individual of specified character.
> The composite of characteristics that make up an individual personality; the self.

**personhood**
pûr′sən-hoo͝d″
noun

> The state or condition of being a person, especially having those qualities that confer distinct individuality.

[Grammerly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/personal-pronouns/)

> A **personal pronoun** is a short word we use as a simple substitute for the proper name of a **person**.

The 1 God, YHWH, uses the **singular** masculine **personal pronoun** to describe **Himself**. So do the 3 **persons** of the trinity.

The 1 true God, is described as having a ***personality***.

Zephaniah 3:17

> YHWH your God in your midst,
> **The Mighty One**, will save;
> He will rejoice over you with gladness,
> He will quiet you with His love,
> He will rejoice over you with singing.”

Isaiah 42:8

> "I am YHWH, ***that is My name***; And My glory I will not give to another, Nor My praise to carved images."

*Note here: YHWH doesn't share His unique glory.  His uniquely supreme nature is only His.*

John 17:3 (*Jesus speaking directly to God Almighty*)

> And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the **only true God**, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent.

### **QUESTION**

***According to the triune concept, there exist 3 eternal persons. How can 3 eternal persons with 3 distinct presences, be the 1 God of Israel?***

> “Hear, O Israel: YHWH our God, **YHWH is one**” (Deuteronomy 6:4).

**God is one.  What is of one in the Trinity doctrine?**

Please solve this equation:

> ***1person+1person+1person=1_____***

- a.) 1 person
- b.) 1 being
- c.) 1 essence
- d.) 1 [other defined noun]

Please define these words so that we can better understand.

- If YHWH is **1 singular person**, how can 3 persons be 1 person and how many personalities?
- If YHWH is **1 being**, how is a being different than a person?  And how many personalities does this being have?
- If YHWH is **1 non personified essence/nature**, please address how He addresses Himself with singular personal pronouns and His personality?

---

Before flagging this question please read:

**Stated rules for duplicates defined from this SE's META:**

*"1.Having one 'perfect' form of a question that contains every possible answer to every slight variation of that question is a myth at best and actively harmful at worst.*

*"2.Having dozens and dozens of variations of the same question is clearly bad.*

*"3.What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question. It is also OK for these duplicates to have their own answers so people who find them don’t have to click yet again to get to a good answer."*

Comment: The header question is different to the 'Question' question. I am not clear as to what is being asked. (Trinitarian doctrine does not obey human-formed mathematics. I would have thought that would be obvious.) And I think some focus would be helpful rather than attempt, with one single question, to define (noting the historical development, through Greek, Latin and English) the words 'person' 'being' and 'essence'.

Comment: Human formed?  Math is found within His creation; within the periodic cycles, etc....   This equation is to assist in the ontology.  Can 3 persons equal 1 persons?  OR if 3 persons can't equal 1 persons.... then what?  The question seeks definitions of words used such as what is in the title.

Comment: I think it would help if you could read up a bit more about 'nature' (Divine nature) and 'person' (Divine Person). Three Persons share one Divine nature. Your reference to 'three persons can't equal one person' is irrelevant. Nobody is suggesting that. Three Persons share one Divine nature and thus there is but one Deity. Prior to the coming of the Son there was a revelation of Deity but only with the coming of the Son is there full revelation.

Comment: I've spoken to many trinitarians who disagree with your last comment.  They say that YHWH has a personality making HIM a being or a person.  I understand what you are saying, but I don't think many who call themselves trinitarians would agree with you.  Do you think Thomas was coming to a realization that the God of Israel is actually not the OT Father but a divine nature, with his exclamation "my God"?

Comment: I think you are still not getting the point. You are now stating that 'the God of Israel is not . . . .  Father but divine nature'. I repeat (yet again) Three Persons share one nature. My person is manifested in and expressed by - my human nature. But that nature is not my person. My person is a spiritual being. I cannot think what else to say to you that you might understand . . . . . . . And this is well developed and widespread trinitarian doctrine. It is not unique to myself. All three Persons may be seen expressed in the OT scriptures.

Comment: The question purports to be about ontology, yet shows lack of appreciation for the theological terms involved in Trinitarian theology and vehemently insists on answering a question without defining the term therein, despite being told numerous times that the term is not a Trinitarian theological concept and that many of the questions as phrased do not make sense in the context. It is not for Trinitarians to prove their doctrine according to your rules.

Answer (score 2):

### Mystery

The very concept of a "Trinity" God is shrouded in ambiguity to the point most Trinitarians agree that it is an unexplainable mystery--both to themselves and to everyone else.  This is why the expression "[mystery of the Holy Trinity](https://www.google.com/search?q=mystery%20of%20the%20Holy%20Trinity)" is so common.

The fact is, there are multiple strains of Trinitarian doctrine, and not all Trinitarians will agree on the most basic definitions of the words *person, personality, being,* or *essence.*

For example, Catholics teach, and always have, that God is *one being*: but Seventh-day Adventist Trinitarians presently teach that God is *[three beings](https://www.adventist.org/trinity/)*, though their Trinitarian doctrine began with God as a single being, prior to which the Seventh-day Adventists did not accept the Trinity at all.

### Variety of Views

A careful explanation of some of the nuances within Adventist Trinitarianism, and indeed, inclusive of most Protestants, can be found [HERE](https://asitreads.com/sda-trinity/), of which I will quote a representative portion below:

> There are two integral factors to a trinity doctrine. This is
> ‘threeness’ and ‘oneness”. As Paul Petersen wrote (as Chair of
> Religion & Professor of the Hebrew Bible, Andrews University):
>
> > “The core elements of the doctrine of the Trinity are oneness and distinctiveness. The Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit are one, yet
> > three. To express this conviction, words and expressions came into use
> > that are not explicitly used in the Bible. The oneness of God we
> > confess by claiming that God is one in being; the distinctiveness we
> > confess by teaching that there are three persons.” (Paul Petersen,
> > Andrews University, May 2015, page 3, ‘God in 3 Persons — in the New
> > Testament’)
>
> While all Trinitarians agree on this core concept, within
> Trinitarianism there can be notable variation from one denomination to
> another or even variants within each denomination. That said, there
> too exists within Adventism, two main notable variations, namely the
> tritheistic and the orthodox variety. . . .
>
> In general, there are three main categories of how trinity or triunity
> is understood:
>
> 1. Consubstantial trinity – This version of trinity is characterized as a single divine “Being,” comprised of three “Persons”, sharing one
>    indivisible (undivided) substance (Catholic/Orthodox trinity and many
>    theologian class of SDA Church who are heavily influenced by
>    evangelical authors would fall under this category ). (“One Being” =
>    “3 Persons”; “Being” and “Person” is distinguished)
> 2. Modalistic trinity – This version of trinity is comprised of three modes or roles occupied by single divine individual wherein one God is
>    manifesting or revealing himself in three different ways, without
>    distinct and coexisting persons in the divine nature. (i.e. Father is
>    Jesus, Father is the Holy Spirit, etc.; same person operating in 3
>    different modes)
> 3. Tritheistic trinity – The “trinity” is comprised of three distinct divine “persons” but they understand “persons” as individual Beings;
>    who all have same power, same nature, purpose, etc. Because they are
>    in agreement in everything they do, they are said to be “one God,” not
>    that all three make up a single Being (Majority of Seventh-day
>    Adventist trinitarians would fall under this category).
>
> > “There were some very early that turned the doctrine of the Trinity into Tritheism, and, instead of three divine persons under the
> > economy of Father, Son, and Holy Spirit, brought in three collateral,
> > co-ordinate, and self-originated beings, making them three absolute
> > and independent principles, without any relation of Father or Son,
> > which is the most proper notion of three gods. And having made this
> > change in the doctrine of the Trinity, they made another change
> > answerable to it in the form of baptism.”–Antiquities, b. 11, chap. 3,
> > § 4.
> >
> > J. H. Waggoner, Signs of the Times, January 27, 1881, pg. 40
> >
> > https://documents.adventistarchives.org/Periodicals/ST/ST18810127-V07-04.pdf
>
> In general, SDA Trinitarians have made the Holy Spirit into a third
> “being” that is essentially the same as the Father and Son, to the
> point where any of them could just as well swap roles and it wouldn’t
> make any difference. The Father could have taken the role of the Son,
> the Son could have taken the role of the Spirit, the Spirit could have
> taken the role of the Father, etc (you can find statements by SDA
> theologians surmising to these sort of ideas further down in this
> article). This is different than the Trinity doctrine taught by other
> churches, which firmly declares that the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit
> are three “persons” inside a SINGLE “being”. So Sunday-keeping
> Trinitarians (as well as Catholics) teach three persons that make up
> one being, whereas Adventist teach three “beings” that are likened to
> 3 individual divine beings belonging to a single family.

### Changing Definitions

One of the biggest problems with understanding the basic elements of Trinitarian belief is that the very word definitions we use have not always carried the same meaning: their definitions have evolved over time.

**Person or Being?**

The word "person" today usually implies "being."  This is at the core of the issue with the doctrinal shift in some denominations toward *tritheism* (three God *beings*).  While most of these Tritheists still consider themselves to be Monotheists, by strict dictionary definitions, they are not.

The word "person" had nothing to do with a "being" when it first came into use.  A review of the dictionary definition for this word, as printed in [Noah Webster's 1828 Dictionary](https://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/person), will suffice to show this.

> **PERSON,** *noun* per'sn. [Latin persona; said to be compounded of per, through or by, and sonus, sound; a Latin word signifying
> primarily a mask used by actors on the stage.]
>
> 1. An individual human being consisting of body and soul. We apply the word to living beings only, possessed of a rational nature; the body
>    when dead is not called a *person*. It is applied alike to a man,
>    woman or child.
>
> A *person* is a thinking intelligent being.
>
> 2. A man, woman or child, considered as opposed to things, or distinct from them.
>
> A zeal for *persons* is far more easy to be perverted, than a zeal for
> things.
>
> 3. A human being, considered with respect to the living body or corporeal existence only. The form of her *person* is elegant.
>
> You'll find her *person* difficult to gain.
>
> The rebels maintained the fight for a small time, and for their
> *persons* showed no want of courage.
>
> 4. A human being, indefinitely; one; a man. Let a *person*'s attainments be never so great, he should remember he is frail and
>    imperfect.
> 5. A human being represented in dialogue, fiction, or on the stage; character. A player appears in the *person* of king Lear.
>
> These tables, Cicero pronounced under the person of Crassus, were of
> more use and authority than all the books of the philosophers.
>
> 6. Character of office.
>
> How different is the same man from himself, as he sustains the
> *person* of a magistrate and that of a friend.
>
> 7. In grammar, the nominative to a verb; the agent that performs or the patient that suffers any thing affirmed by a verb; as, I write; he
>    is smitten; she is beloved; the rain descends in torrents. I, thou or
>    you, he, she or it, are called the first, second and third persons.
>    Hence we apply the word *person* to the termination or modified form
>    of the verb used in connection with the persons; as the first or the
>    third *person* of the verb; the verb is in the second *person*.
> 8. In law, an artificial *person* is a corporation or body politic.
>
> In *person* by one's self; with bodily presence; not be
> representative.
>
> The king in *person* visits all around.
>
> **PER'SON,** *verb transitive* To represent as a *person*; to make to resemble; to image. [*Not in use.*]

So a *person* was actually more equivalent to a *role*; especially as could be applied to God, who is clearly not a human.  Note that of the eight senses of meaning provided by Webster, only the sixth could reasonably be applied to God, as God is neither human, nor a mere point of grammar.  Clearly this "person" does not connote "being."

But modern dictionaries have changed the rhetoric.  For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person) defines *person* as:

> A **person** (PL: **people**) is a being who has certain capacities or
> attributes such as reason, morality, consciousness or
> self-consciousness, and being a part of a culturally established form
> of social relations such as kinship, ownership of property, or legal
> responsibility. The defining features of personhood and,
> consequently, what makes a person count as a person, differ widely
> among cultures and contexts.
>
> *[NOTE: Wikipedia's references clashed with those of Stack Exchange, and have been stripped.]*

What was once a *role* or *character of office* has morphed into *a being*.

But Wikipedia also notes the historical development of the word:

> **Development of the concept**
>
> In ancient Rome, the word *persona* (Latin) or *prosopon* (πρόσωπον;
> Ancient Greek) originally referred to the masks worn by actors on
> stage. The various masks represented the various "personae" in the
> stage play.

Those who are oblivious to these historical changes are the most susceptible to accepting revised beliefs that were not accepted in previous times.

## Summary

A person is a role, and a single being can have more than one role; therefore a single being *can* be represented as multiple persons.  As an example, the same man might relate to his family members in the person of a father, or that of a son, or that of a husband.  A *multi-being* God, however, implies *Tritheism*, and technically no longer represents monotheistic belief--or the belief in "one God."

The word "essence" is, to the author of this post, beyond discussion with respect to God.  No human can know what God is made of, and His essence, or substance, is not addressed in Scripture, nor should it be mentioned.  However, many do presume to address it--I will let them find their own manner of defending such.

Comment: Okay, maybe some small changes would be enough to remove the confusion then. In particular maybe this sentence could put trinity in quotes? "In general, there are three main categories of how trinity or triunity is understood" But I also think it would be helpful to more clearly state that the true/official/orthodox version of Trinitarianism, for better or worse, is the Nicene version.

Comment: @curiousdannii The difficulty here lies in the fact that the quoted portion in my answer contained quotes of its own, so I put those in quote sections and put the larger quote between horizontal lines. I did not find a way of making this clear enough even to my own satisfaction, but am at a loss as to how to improve it.  The portion you desire to have in quotation marks is part of that quote, and was not originally in quotation marks. Were it part of _my own_ remarks, I would readily consent. Further, the question is not asking the definition of Trinity, so the Nicene Creed seems out of place.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that was all a quote. I'd say you should mark it all up with a quote, rather than using horizontal lines.

Comment: "therefore a single being can be represented as multiple persons" And when representing Himself in  those particular personas, is He still that single being?

Comment: @Biblasia Your summary/conclusion is flawed.  What your doing is comparing three "offices" in reference to the trinity to "ontological beings." That is an invalid comparison. The doctrine of the trinity does not merely reduce the persons of the trinity to "roles." The Bible clearly regards the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit as actual "persons." Ontology in its simplest from is the study of existence. God exist, period. He does not exist in "modes/roles." Using your example above! What if a person does not have children he can't be a father. What if he never gets married, continued.

Comment: Continued: If a person never gets married they cannot be a husband or wife assuming it's a woman. Oneness Pentecostals use the same argument your putting forth here and it won't wash. In their "Modalistic" theology Jesus plays the role or is in the mode of being the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit all wrapped up in one god/person, who's name is Jesus Christ. And yes, Gods essence or nature is addressed in Scripture. Hebrews 1:1-2 for starters. Strong's Lexicon #5287

Comment: This answer would be improved by referencing the First Council of Niceae which outlined some of the initial concepts underlying Trinitarianism; e.g that the Father and the Son are of the same substance (homoousion/consubstantial). Defining person as "role" is imprecise since that conflates with modalism which is definitely distinct. Likewise, lumping in SDA trinitarianism conflates the issue since most Trinitarians would reject that as Tritheism (just as they would consider Mormon's view of the Godhead incompatible)

Comment: @eques Unfortunately, I've already been around this stump several times with curiousdannii already but my comments got deleted. I won't repeat it all, but the OP is not asking about a creed...the OP is asking about the very words themselves that some creeds might choose to use. If you think that the Nicaean Creed defines "person", "being", and "essence" sufficiently to satisfy the OP, please post this in your answer--I'm sure the OP would appreciate it.  Notably, your own answer to the question does NOT contain any reference to the Nicaean Creed, nor to Nicaea at all.

Comment: I never said OP was asking about a creed as creed; however, OP is asking about Trinitarian Ontology which does stem from the councils decree. I also said the council not specifically its creed although the creed does describe the homoousion aspect which does relate to the question of ontology. Nor did I claim that the Council defines it to OP's exacting standard. I merely said it would improve your answer. I also pointed out some other points about your answer. Come to think of it, if you are going to discuss person (Esp cf prosopon), you actually should reference Chalcedon as well.

Comment: My answer may not reference Niceae, but it does reference Augustine and indirectly Boethius and Aquinas; hence, I do refer to established authorities of Trinitarian doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

The question your asking is flawed. "According to the triune concept, there exist 3 eternal persons." That is "NOT" the concept of the Trinity. Let me now define "being" and "person."

Being: the state or fact of existing; existence. something that exists or is thought to exist.

Person/Personality: is the combination of characteristics or qualities that form an individuals distinctive character.

Now, by "Trinity" I mean within the nature of the ONE true God, there are three eternal, distinct Persons: the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit. These three persons are the ONE God. By using the logical technique called the transitive property of equality (things equal to the same thing are equal to each other).

The Bible teaches that there is only one uncreated, eternal, true God (Exodus 3:14; Deuteronomy 6:4; John 17:3). The Bible teaches that there will never be any other uncreated eternal, true God(s) to come into existence (Isaiah 43:24; 44:6-8; 1 Corinthians 8:4-6; Galatians 4:8).

The Bible teaches that this ONE true God created everything ex-nihilo, or from nothing (Psalm 90:2; Isaiah 44:24; Hebrews 3:4; 11:3).

When we say "the Father is God," we mean that a distinct person known as the Father is identifiable as the ONE true God, the creator ex-nihilo (2 Peter 1:17). When we say "the Son is God," we mean that a distinct person known as the Son is identifiable as the ONE true God, the creator ex-nihilo (John 1:1-3; Colossians 1:16).

When we say "the Holy Spirit is God," we mean that a distinct person known as the Holy Spirit is identifiable as the ONE true God, the creator ex-nihilo (Job 33:4; Acts 5:3-4; 1 Corinthians 2:11).

Therefore, as the transitive property of equality shows us, the three Persons Are the One God, (Matthew 28:19). It has been asked that there are so many scriptures that only use Lord, God and many other titles referring to God. God said my glory will I not give to another...Is this all 3 speaking or is it only one of the three persons?

Where no distinction is made, it is obviously unnecessary to make a distinction. The persons of the Trinity are persons in relation to each other, any one of the persons in relation to us is simply God. If you are in a relationship with the Father/Son/Holy Spirit, then you must be in a relationship with them all, for there is only ONE God. If you deny one, you deny all.

Comment: This is not a math problem.  I think your use of the transitive property of equality is wrong and weakens your argument. >>>>  if a = b and a = c, then b = c.  You haven't demonstrated this.   You say *"things equal to the same thing are equal to each other"*..... but Jesus is not equal to the Father and the holy spirit is not equal to Jesus.  There is a hierarchy even within this being that you are defining.

Comment: How many personalities (if any) does this divine being have?  *"Being: the state or fact of existing; existence. something that exists or is thought to exist.:"*  Your definition keeps it vague.  Is the being personified or not?  If not, you ignored the critical sub question.  I'll repeat it here.  ***If YHWH is a non personified essence/nature, please address how He addresses Himself with singular personal pronouns and His personality?***  Without answering this... you haven't answered the question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with my math. What's wrong is your not understanding the Biblical teaching of the Trinity. I said in my post, "Within the nature of the ONE true God, there are three eternal, distinct Persons: " This means that the Persons of the trinity are "ONE IN NATURE." They are 3 distinct in persons. Look, your one in nature with your parents, yet you are a distinct person from your parents. The Jews at John 5:18 accused Jesus of blasphemy for making Himself equal to His Father. Same thing at John 10:30-33 for Jesus making Himself out God.

Comment: Continued. And the same thing at Matthew 26:63-65. The high priest Caiaphas ask Jesus to swear as to His identity. "I adjure You by the living God, that You tell us whether Your are the Christ/Messiah, the Son of God." At vs65 Caiaphas tore his robes and said, "He has blasphemed!" What was the blasphemy? In all of this I am "NOT" talking about a hierarchy within the Godhead although there is a hierarchy. This is based on Philippians 2:5-10 when Jesus took the form a bond-servant/man. And btw, the Jews knew exactly what Jesus was claiming. If they didn't know what Jesus meant, you can't know.

Comment: **"They are 3 distinct in persons. Look, your one in nature with your parents, yet you are a distinct person from your parents."**  I'm not exclusively the same nature as my parents.  I am of the same nature as every human that has not been yet been glorified.  And I  don't go around referring to all of mankind as "ME", "I", "MINE".... Can you not see a difference?  Again, every child of God is said to receive this divine nature after our resurrection.  Peter states this outright as I have shared.....

Comment: Still waiting for you to finish answering the question.  This includes the sub question 3 which correlates to your answer of 1 Essence/Nature.

Comment: Re: Matt 26:63-65.... Jesus addresses the Jews accusing him of blasphemy. *"John 10 >>>34 Jesus answered them, “Is it not written in your law, ‘I said, “You are gods” ’? 35 If He called them gods, to whom the word of God came (and the Scripture cannot be broken), 36 do you say of Him whom the Father sanctified and sent into the world, ‘You are blaspheming,’ because I said, ‘I am the Son of God’?"*  **Jesus says he is the SON OF GOD and they accuse him of blasphemy. NOT GOD**

Comment: More excuses! I'm not scoped. No answer on the "sub" question. The formula is wrong. To many personalities. There's a hierarchy and the Son of God is not God. What about what John 5:18 where the Jews accused Him of being EQUAL with God? Or John 10:30-33 where Jews accused Him of actually being God? Thomas called Him God. Peter called Him God, John called Him God and the Apostle Paul. Is everybody lying? What would you accept as proof? The Jews have the "son of" idiom. Jesus is the Son of God which indicates the shared nature between the father and the son. What's the nature of Jesus' Father?

Comment: Your answer is still ignoring the most important part of the question.... I'll repeat it a third time.... ***If YHWH is a non personified essence/nature, please address how He addresses Himself with singular personal pronouns and His personality?*** Without answering this... you haven't answered the question.

Comment: "Without answering this.." He hasn't answered because the question as phrased is nonsensical to Trinitarians.

Comment: After reading this answer again... I can't find the actual answer to my question.  Is God 1 essence, 1 being, or 1 person?  Also his opening sentence is surprising to say the least..... "***According to the triune concept, there exist 3 eternal persons. That is NOT the concept of the Trinity."***  ...... Come again?  What of God is 1?

Comment: *"Being: .....something that exists or is thought to exist."* >>>>>  Is a grain of sand a being?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than cherry pick verses, one should begin by focusing attention on the **first time** God chooses to make a first person identification of Himself:

> <sup>26</sup> Then God said, “Let **Us** make man in **Our** image, according to **Our** likeness; let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, over the birds of the air, and over the cattle, over all the earth and over every creeping thing that creeps on the earth.” <sup>27</sup> So God created man in His own image; in the image of God He created him; male and female He created them. (Genesis 1)

Any one who begins with Genesis knows the first form of self-identification God chose was using **plural** masculine pronouns. Rather then deny God was confused or is unable to accurate identify Himself, the logical approach is to consider, "Who is included in us?"

Nor is this first use some mystery or grammatical aberration. The plural and singular use makes good sense. Sometimes YHVH acts or speaks singularly. That is, "He" is one of the "us" in God's first self reference.

A rational explanation for understanding why God chose to make this first reference of Himself as plural, is recognizing He is stating His nature. Attempting to deny the explicit text on the basis of the inadequacy of **human** definitions and terminology of persons or personhood is not an explanation for how or why God chose to first identify Himself as **plural**.

The plural nature of God continues throughout the Old Testament. God can be *Elohim*, or *Eloah*, or *El*. Why does Scripture need three different words, one of which is plural to identify God? Do translations which conflate three different words to just one, *God*, justify dismissing the fact God chose to **first** identify Himself as plural?

The Shema is often cited as "proof" of the singleness of God:

> “Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD *is* one! (Deuteronomy 6)
> שְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵינוּ יְהוָה אֶחָֽד

The literal translation is *Hear Israel YHVH Elohim YHVH one*. Like the use of the first person pronoun, this makes perfect sense when it is understood with the passage in Genesis in view: *And Elohim said, "Let **us** make...Hear Israel YHVH Elohim YHVH one.* Moses does **not** say ***Elohim*** is one. He affirms *YHVH Elohim* and *YHVH* are one.

**Conclusion**
I believe there are two legitimate criticisms of Christian ontology of the Trinity:

1. Replacing Biblical terminology with human terms.
2. Conflating the three different Hebrew terms to a single word, *God*.

With respect to the first, consider this simple statement from Paul:

> For through him we both have access in one Spirit to the Father. (Ephesians 2:18)
> `ὅτι δι᾽ αὐτοῦ ἔχομεν τὴν προσαγωγὴν οἱ ἀμφότεροι ἐν ἑνὶ πνεύματι πρὸς τὸν πατέρα`

No ontology or discussions of persons, but Paul clearly states there are three each with a different role in the *oneness* of God:

```
Son: δι᾽ αὐτοῦ [through Him]
Spirit: ἐν ἑνὶ πνεύματι [in one Spirit]
Father: πρὸς τὸν πατέρα [to the Father]
```

Each of the three is described with a different preposition. Through,  `διά` the Son, and with, `ἐν` one Spirit, and to `πρὸς` the Father. The last is better understood by what John later writes:

```
Prologue: the Word was     πρὸς τὸν θεόν  
Ephesians: the believer is πρὸς τὸν πατέρα
```

Paul's Trinitarian nail in the coffin is absence of the word, *God*. How is this oversight **best** explained? When Paul writes Father he means *God*. or when Paul writes Father he means, *Father*. God is clearly present in Paul's statement when the text is seen that Paul means exactly what he wrote - God is to be found through the Son, in one Spirit, `πρὸς` the Father.

Lastly, if translators stopped conflating **three different** Hebrew words as *God* and accurately conveyed the original text by transliterating *Elohim*, *El*, and *Eloha*, the reality of the triune nature of God would not be in question.

Comment: YHWH did not make man as a triune being/essence/person. He made us in His image as singular persons who can relate to our singular Father. "Us" can be interpreted many ways to account for its few use cases, therefore such instances provide light support for multiple persons being YHWH.  I'm not "asserting" He uses singular masculine personal pronouns. He objectively ***does*** without assertion.  YHWH uses singular masculine pronouns hundreds,...... maybe thousands of times.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore I think you misunderstood. I did not say man was made as a triune being. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yes much better thank you.  However, It begs the same question.... In what way did the Triune YHWH make us is their image?  We aren't triune.  We aren't eternally begotten as children, we aren't indwelling spirits? ....Rather if we take HIS description of Himself as Truth, we can see that every singular person has hands, feet, mouth, etc...just as He says He does.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore First, the question is about God not man. Second, man is more than a body. You could find triune as body, soul, spirit. Clearly man did not become a living being until the body received breath from God. Finally, eternally begotten as children does not line up with the NT. Based on the entire Bible, one could reason man has an initial state, can be reborn or is a new creation as Paul says, and will be like Him. Since each is unlike the other but each is the individual there is a similarity. The difference is the three do not exist or are present simultaneously.

Comment: There is only spirit, flesh, and the 1 eternal Spirit of our Father.  What is the distinction between the soul(as you are using it) and each of our individualized spirit.... the seeds of thee Spirit?  I'm still not seeing how mankind is in the image of a triune being/essence.

Answer (score 1):

> How can 3 eternal persons with 3 distinct presences, be the God of Israel, without violating the rational laws of mathematics?

Because mathematics doesn't directly enter into it, the question doesn't make sense. That is, mathematics is the science of numbers or alternatively, it is the branch of knowledge related to number as abstracted from other types of knowledge.

> 1person+1person+1person=1_____

There is a term which could go into that blank or rather, there is a term which conventionally would appear to fit; however, the equation suggests something which is fundamentally at odds with Trinitarian theology.

Three persons do not "make up" the 1 _____; that is, they are not "parts" or components which together constitute the entirety, which is what addition would suggest.

God is "3 Persons 1 essence or nature". (Cf, Augustine, de Trinitate VII 4,8)

Alternatively we might say "God is 3 persons of 1 essence or nature" as Aquinas does, but we must make a key distinction. In Latin, this would be expressed as "Deus est tres personas unius essentiae vel naturae"; that is, it uses what is grammatically known as the genitive case. It's important to note that it does not use any of the prepositions that might be translated as "of" such as *e/ex* (out of) or *de* (from) since the former often implies a material cause (e.g. "the table is made from wood" -> mensa est ex ligno) and the latter often implies separation, departure etc,

Initially, ***person*** was used simply to mean "what there are 3 of in God" (as Augustine put it); that is, the term was used as a name for the concept so that constant explanation would be unneeded. Incidentally, the word "person" as we use it today was not yet in common usage. Later, person was defined by Boethius to mean an individual hypostasis of a rational nature.

A ***being*** is something which has existence; more specifically, God is not only a being, but is Being. That is, God is existence and everything else that exists only exists by participating in his existence.

An essence is what makes a thing to be what it is. In particular, God because He is simple and pure act, his being (existence) is his essence -- that is, He is divinity. In contrast, an individual human has existence (being) but participates in the essence of humanity.

The Persons are distinct or distinguishable only by their relations with each other, specifically relations of opposition. The Father is not the Son because paternity is opposed to filiation (son-ship).

*Personality* is not a theological term; that is, there's not really a definition of personality in use that really makes sense in relation to God. Furthermore, if I say 1, you'd question why 3 persons and if I say 3, you'd say then how is God one. Perhaps the point you are aiming at with "personality" is the distinctiveness aspect, but even then, we'd have to say the only distinctiveness is the Persons and they are only distinguished by their mutually opposed relations (Father <-> Son, Father and Son <-> the Holy Spirit) since each person is the essence.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147448/discussion-on-answer-by-eques-trinitarian-ontology-what-is-it-being-vs-perso); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Trinitarian [Ontology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology)... What is it? Being vs person vs essence vs _______**

The subject matter of the Divine Nature of the Trinity has been debated over for centuries. I have had Unitarians tell me that the term Trinity was coined in the Middle Ages. Nothing is further from the truth.

St. Augustine of Hippo (354-430) had already written 15 books on the Trinity [(*De Trinitate*)](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/1301.htm). It seems the classic works of Christendom are little read, appreciated and understood in modern times.

The Angelic Doctor St. Thomas Aquinas equally wrote on the Divine Nature of the Trinity.

The Church has many sources about it, yet many nowadays prefer to squabble over definitions already defined. People that have their minds set up on a particular outcome usually will not change their minds. Only grace can help with that. This stated I am not posting this answer for a debate.

St. Thomas Aquinas has the following to say about the Trinity and it’s Divine Nature and Essence.

> [Question 39. The persons in relation to the essence](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1039.htm)
>
> **1. Whether in God the essence is the same as the person?**
>
> The truth of this question is quite clear if we consider the divine simplicity. For it was shown above (I:3:3) that the divine simplicity requires that in God essence is the same as "suppositum," which in intellectual substances is nothing else than person. But a difficulty seems to arise from the fact that while the divine persons are multiplied, the essence nevertheless retains its unity. And because, as Boethius says (De Trin. i), "relation multiplies the Trinity of persons," some have thought that in God essence and person differ, forasmuch as they held the relations to be "adjacent"; considering only in the relations the idea of "reference to another," and not the relations as realities. But as it was shown above (I:28:2) in creatures relations are accidental, whereas in God they are the divine essence itself. Thence it follows that in God essence is not really distinct from person; and yet that the persons are really distinguished from each other. For person, as above stated (I:29:4, signifies relation as subsisting in the divine nature. But relation as referred to the essence does not differ therefrom really, but only in our way of thinking; while as referred to an opposite relation, it has a real distinction by virtue of that opposition. Thus there are one essence and three persons.
>
> **Article 2. Whether it must be said that the three persons are of one essence?**
>
> As above explained (I:13:2), divine things are named by our intellect, not as they really are in themselves, for in that way it knows them not; but in a way that belongs to things created. And as in the objects of the senses, whence the intellect derives its knowledge, the nature of the species is made individual by the matter, and thus the nature is as the form, and the individual is the "suppositum" of the form; so also in God the essence is taken as the form of the three persons, according to our mode of signification. Now in creatures we say that every form belongs to that whereof it is the form; as the health and beauty of a man belongs to the man. But we do not say of that which has a form, that it belongs to the form, unless some adjective qualifies the form; as when we say: "That woman is of a handsome figure," or: "This man is of perfect virtue." In like manner, as in God the persons are multiplied, and the essence is not multiplied, we speak of one essence of the three persons, and three persons of the one essence, provided that these **genitives** be understood as designating the form.
>
> **Article 3. Whether essential names should be predicated in the singular of the three persons?**
>
> Some essential names signify the essence after the manner of substantives; while others signify it after the manner of adjectives. Those which signify it as substantives are predicated of the three persons in the singular only, and not in the plural. Those which signify the essence as adjectives are predicated of the three persons in the plural. The reason of this is that substantives signify something by way of substance, while adjectives signify something by way of accident, which adheres to a subject. Now just as substance has existence of itself, so also it has of itself unity or multitude; wherefore the singularity or plurality of a substantive name depends upon the form signified by the name. But as accidents have their existence in a subject, so they have unity or plurality from their subject; and therefore the singularity and plurality of adjectives depends upon their "supposita." In creatures, one form does not exist in several "supposita" except by unity of order, as the form of an ordered multitude. So if the names signifying such a form are substantives, they are predicated of many in the singular, but otherwise if they adjectives. For we say that many men are a college, or an army, or a people; but we say that many men are collegians. Now in God the divine essence is signified by way of a form, as above explained (Article 2), which, indeed, is simple and supremely one, as shown above (I:3:7; I:11:4). So, names which signify the divine essence in a substantive manner are predicated of the three persons in the singular, and not in the plural. This, then, is the reason why we say that Socrates, Plato and Cicero are "three men"; whereas we do not say the Father, Son and Holy Ghost are "three Gods," but "one God"; forasmuch as in the three "supposita" of human nature there are three humanities, whereas in the three divine Persons there is but one divine essence. On the other hand, the names which signify essence in an adjectival manner are predicated of the three persons plurally, by reason of the plurality of "supposita." For we say there are three "existent" or three "wise" beings, or three "eternal," "uncreated," and "immense" beings, if these terms are understood in an adjectival sense. But if taken in a substantive sense, we say "one uncreated, immense, eternal being," as Athanasius declares.
>
> **Article 4. Whether the concrete essential names can stand for the person?**
>
> Some have said that this name "God" and the like, properly according to their nature, stand for the essence, but by reason of some notional adjunct are made to stand for the Person. This opinion apparently arose from considering the divine simplicity, which requires that in God, He "who possesses" and "what is possessed" be the same. So He who possesses Godhead, which is signified by the name God, is the same as Godhead. But when we consider the proper way of expressing ourselves, the mode of signification must be considered no less than the thing signified. Hence as this word "God" signifies the divine essence as in Him Who possesses it, just as the name "man" signifies humanity in a subject, others more truly have said that this word "God," from its mode of signification, can, in its proper sense, stand for person, as does the word "man." So this word "God" sometimes stands for the essence, as when we say "God creates"; because this predicate is attributed to the subject by reason of the form signified—that is, Godhead. But sometimes it stands for the person, either for only one, as when we say, "God begets," or for two, as when we say, "God spirates"; or for three, as when it is said: "To the King of ages, immortal, invisible, the only God," etc. (1 Timothy 1:17).
>
> **Article 5. Whether abstract essential names can stand for the person?**
>
> Concerning this, the abbot Joachim erred in asserting that as we can say "God begot God," so we can say "Essence begot essence": considering that, by reason of the divine simplicity God is nothing else but the divine essence. In this he was wrong, because if we wish to express ourselves correctly, we must take into account not only the thing which is signified, but also the mode of its signification as above stated (Article 4). Now although "God" is really the same as "Godhead," nevertheless the mode of signification is not in each case the same. For since this word "God" signifies the divine essence in Him that possesses it, from its mode of signification it can of its own nature stand for person. Thus the things which properly belong to the persons, can be predicated of this word, "God," as, for instance, we can say "God is begotten" or is "Begetter," as above explained (Article 4). The word "essence," however, in its mode of signification, cannot stand for Person, because it signifies the essence as an abstract form. Consequently, what properly belongs to the persons whereby they are distinguished from each other, cannot be attributed to the essence. For that would imply distinction in the divine essence, in the same way as there exists distinction in the "supposita."
>
> **Article 6. Whether the persons can be predicated of the essential terms?**
>
> As above explained (Article 5), although adjectival terms, whether personal or notional, cannot be predicated of the essence, nevertheless substantive terms can be so predicated, owing to the real identity of essence and person. The divine essence is not only really the same as one person, but it is really the same as the three persons. Whence, one person, and two, and three, can be predicated of the essence as if we were to say, "The essence is the Father, and the Son, and the Holy Ghost." And because this word "God" can of itself stand for the essence, as above explained (Article 4, Reply to Objection 3), hence, as it is true to say, "The essence is the three persons"; so likewise it is true to say, "God is the three persons."
>
> **Article 7. Whether the essential names should be appropriated to the persons?**
>
> For the manifestation of our faith it is fitting that the essential attributes should be appropriated to the persons. For although the trinity of persons cannot be proved by demonstration, as was above expounded (I:32:1, nevertheless it is fitting that it be declared by things which are more known to us. Now the essential attributes of God are more clear to us from the standpoint of reason than the personal properties; because we can derive certain knowledge of the essential attributes from creatures which are sources of knowledge to us, such as we cannot obtain regarding the personal properties, as was above explained (I:32:1. As, therefore, we make use of the likeness of the trace or image found in creatures for the manifestation of the divine persons, so also in the same manner do we make use of the essential attributes. And such a manifestation of the divine persons by the use of the essential attributes is called "appropriation."

Comment: ***For it was shown above (I:3:3) that the divine simplicity requires that in God essence is the same as "suppositum," which in intellectual substances is nothing else than person.***  Can you please explain this?

Comment: Can you explain your answer in your own words?