How do Trinitarians reconcile Jesus' words in John 5:31 with the view that GOD the Father / the Son / the Holy Spirit are the same being?
In John 5:31, Jesus said the following:

If I testify about myself, my testimony is not true. There is another
who testifies in my favour, and I know that his testimony about me is
true. ‘You have sent to John and he has testified to the truth. Not
that I accept human testimony; but I mention it that you may be
saved. John was a lamp that burned and gave light, and you chose for a
time to enjoy his light. ‘I have testimony weightier than that of
John. For **the works that the Father has given me to finish – the
very works that I am doing – testify that the Father has sent me. And
the Father who sent me has himself testified concerning me. (John
5:31-37)

Jesus spoke for himself as the Son of God, but said "if I testify about myself, my testimony is not true". It means that his word alone would not suffice for the testimony to be established as proof legally in front of human judges. Jesus refers to John the Baptist as a human witness but adds that "he doesn't accept a human testimony" for "I receive not honour from men" (John 5:41 - KJV).
Witnesses acceptable to Jesus' standards of perfection were "the works that the Father has given [Christ] to finish", and in connection with those works, "the Father who sent [Christ] has himself testified concerning [Jesus].
He repeated similar words in John 8:17, 18

In your own Law it is written that the testimony of two witnesses is
true. I am one who testifies for myself; my other witness is the
Father, who sent me. (John 8:17-18)

Jesus says "in your own Law it is written that the testimony of two witnesses is true". He clearly follows that Law as well in John 5:31-37 in regards to the legality of his witness. Who are the two witnesses Jesus mentions in John 8:17,18? Himself and the Father!
According to the Athanasian Creed, the Trinity is “one God in Trinity, and Trinity in Unity;” and that you can’t “confound the persons nor divide the substance.”
Albeit being 3 separate persons, they are consubstantial and “coequal” for “Such as the Father is, such is the Son, and such is the Holy Spirit”
The persons are all almighty, “and yet they are not three almighties, but one almighty.... they are not three Gods, but one God.”
It goes as far as to say that it is “forbidden by the catholic religion to say; There are three Gods or three Lords.” The three persons of the Trinity are inseparable and ONE being.
The Doctrine of Circuminsession (perichoresis) says:

The subsistences [divine persons] then we say are perfect, that we
may not conceive of the divine nature as compound. For compoundness is
the beginning of separation. And again we speak of the three
subsistences as being in each other , that we may not introduce a
crowd and multitude of Gods. Owing to the three subsistences, there is
no compoundness or confusion: while, owing to their having the same
essence and dwelling in one another, and being the same in will, and
energy, and power, and authority, and movement, so to speak, we
recognise the indivisibility and the unity of God. For verily there is
one God, and His word and Spirit.

According to the theologian studies on the Lutheran Trinity Doctrine, Reiner Jansen said the following:

The"works of the Trinity cannot be lined up alongside one another in
such a way that they stand as three isolated and disparate events. The
work of any given person is always seen in relation to the work of the
other two persons. And so the work of the Father, Son, and Spirit are
not considered in and of themselves, but are seen entirely in the
light of the Trinitarian faith" (Jansen, 84)

Dr. Charles P. Arand adds to this:

for there exists an intimate interdependence, one might even say a
mutual dependence among their works.

James E. Dolezal states:

“The doctrine of divine simplicity teaches that (1) God is identical
with his existence and his essence and (2) that each of his attributes
is ontologically identical with his existence and with every other one
of his attributes.”
― James E. Dolezal, God without Parts: Divine
Simplicity and the Metaphysics of God's Absoluteness

If the trinitarian dogma is true, that "the Father, the Word, and the Holy Spirit… are one" (1. John 5:7 - KJV) "ontologically identical" in essence and being, then the "witness" they are bearing about each other is legally unacceptable by the Judaic Law that God himself established!
Even if you say that God the Father, God the Son, God the Holy Spirit are different persons of the God-Head, it would still be legally unacceptable due to the very nature of God's subsistence according to the Trinity dogma: The three persons are one and the same being: GOD.
Legally speaking you cannot separate the witness from the being giving the witness. If the three persons of the Trinity are ONE in essence, nature, power, action, and will, and thus cannot say, act, and will differently from each other, then we cannot get three separate, distinct or independent testimonies from it, but only one. For there is no variation in point of view or dependence, that would warrant it to be accepted as a separate independent witness. Jesus' own words would apply that "if I testify about myself [my identity], my testimony is not true".
It would mean that if any person of the God-Head, testifies about any other person of the God-Head or about the God-Head itself, according to the judicial Law established by God/YHWH himself, this testimony alone would not be acceptable to Jewish judges abiding to that Law.

2 Corinthians 13:1 also has wrongdoing as it's focus, as does Matthew 18.

@MikeBorden - you're not wrong. We're talking about establishing facts or legally acceptable proof in a judicial setting. Wasn't it accusations of wrongdoing that Jesus defended himself against in John chapters 5, 8 and 10? He was accused of not telling the truth or blaspheming, so he had to establish the truthful legally acceptable witness/proof that what he said was true.

@MikeBorden - I changed the statement in the OP to reflect this.

Is "ontologically the same" terminology you've seen Trinitarians actually use?

@curiousdannii - Indeed JAMES DOLEZAL or Dr. JAMES WHITE use the term often in the the philosophical explanation of God's being. Being ontologically the same means sharing one essence and being. 3 persons being consubstantial, being the same identity, being inseparable in will, action, power, and nature from each other. Ontologically the same in the sense of how St. Thomas Aquinas’ Summa theologiae explains it.

Ah, Dolezal is a trustworthy theologian on doctrine of God. (Unfortunately James White does not have an accredited doctorate.) Please [edit] this to include a quote from Dolezal. Meanwhile the rest of this could be substantially condensed. God is not bound to the laws he sets for humans, so you can just leave it as how can John be talking about different testimonies if the persons are ontologically the same.

The question is at fault, fundamentally. Trinitarians do not accept that the three Persons of the Godhead are one person. Therefore, the persons are separate witnesses. Introducing the term 'ontological' (never found anywhere in scripture) does not assist this particular question. The term is introduced to try to convey the unity of Deity. That is to say, the unity of the Divine nature. (Not the concept of one person.) That Divine persons share one divine nature does not deny them the ability to act as separate witnesses, as separate individual persons.

@NigelJ - as the three distinct but inseparable personas of one identity (God), and each fully representing or being the identity of GOD, no separate / distinct witness is possible. Otherwise you’d have to separate them. In modern judicial settings, separate witnesses are not allowed to talk to each other, so that they can’t influence each others witness. If they are inseparable, their witness is unacceptable.

@JsWitness "The three personas share one and the same identity: Trinity GOD." Do you have a Trinitarian source who teaches this? Again, you need to provide the basis for your question by giving us your sources, not just your own ideas. Because that's not a statement I'd be very happy with, and I'm sure many other Trinitarians would agree!

@JsWitness no separate / distinct witness is possible. and If they are inseparable, their witness is unacceptable.. This is just not true. Can family members not testify on each others' behalf ? May a husband and wife not witness of each other ? And this above all . . . . . . may conjoined identical (so-called 'Siamese') twins not witness on behalf of one another ? ? ! What Court would deny such an 'inseparable' witness ?  Not so. Not so at all. You have just not thought this through at all.

@NigelJ - Distinct family members don’t share one identity. They are separate identities. The individual members are not consubstantial. They act and will differently - are having separate point of views which render their witness separate. Even family members are asked to not concoct / negotiate a witness, and it is up to the judge to decide whether such a family witness is credible.

@curiousdannii - https://philpapers.org/s/Trinity%20identity - Philosophers of Religious Studies use the terms “Ontology” and “Identity” in relation to the Trinity all the time.

@JsWitness But which of those authors are actually Trinitarians? And are they using "identity" in the personal sense or the mathematical sense? And are they saying what you're actually saying here? And of course what Philosophers of Religious Studies say is irrelevant - go ask about what they say on [philosophy.se] instead. Searching for collocations of two words isn't evidence that Trinitarians are saying what you're claiming they are. That really just looks like you're searching for quotes after the fact, rather than starting from Trinitarian teachings.

@JsWitness There you go again - hiding behind the word 'identity' which you give a meaning all of your own manufacture. This is very poor stuff. There is no substantial argument here at all. No further comment.

@curiousdannii - the vast majority of them declare themselves to be trinitarians - you just need to read some of their papers. They use the terms in connection with the definitions of the Trinity as described in the various creeds of the Catholic and Orthodox churches. I could quote the Athanasian and Nicene Creed on what they say about the Trinity but sum it up in modern terms. I may give a definition in the posted question for these terms if that helps, but to me at least it’s self-explanatory.

What you need to do is [edit] this question to provide specific quotes and then base the question around those quotes. I'm not sure why you haven't just added the quote from James Dolezal that you said you already had! And questions based on the Nicene/Athanasian Creeds are of course very welcome.

@NigelJ - “Identity” according to Oxford Lexicon is: the fact of being who or what a person or thing is. I don’t make up terms or concoct my own definitions. I take what the various mainline church creeds tell me about the trinity. You can now act as a witness to prove the creed’s definition wrong. What I understood from your answer is that you don’t fully agree with the said creeds but venture into a sort of united polytheism. You thus avoided reconciling the trinity with Jesus asserting of 2 separate witnesses. Fair enough - your views are your views. I respect it.

@curiousdannii - I've made some adjustments, and hope it fits better like this. I've added quotes from the Athanasian Creed as well as quotes from the official doctrine of Circuminsession. I removed the term "ontological" from the question as I recon that it may cause confusion as to what is meant.

I cut some unnecessary discussion to try to help focus the question. But that still leaves this key problem: you are making this assertion with zero evidence: "according to the Trinity dogma: The three personas are one and the same identity/being: GOD." Being yes, identity no. Because the being of God is not the same as the being of humans, the persons being one being does not imply they have only one witness. So really your argument is hinges on them being the same identity, but you've given no reason to think that is what Trinitarians think.

I half think you should add ontological back, as you said you had clear usage from James Dolezal, which is better than this identity phrasing you're currently using. Also, you keep writing "persona", which is not generally considered acceptable Trinitarian terminology, as it smells like modalism. Trinitarians are usually very strict: the father, son, and spirit are persons, not personas.

Do you refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perichoresis

@curiousdannii - when the Athanasian Creed states that "the Father IS God, the Son IS God, and the Holy Spirit IS God", isn't it describing what the distinct personas of the Trinity ARE. The Oxford Dictionary defines the term "identity" as "the fact of being who or what a person or thing IS." Isn't it common sense that we attribute identity to a being? https://www.gotquestions.org/ontological-Trinity.html

@curiousdannii - as the term "identity" appears to cause issues, I removed it as well from the OP.

@JsWitness I am human, you are human. We have the same identity in that respect. That obviously doesn't mean we can't be distinct witnesses. Anyways, aside from the problem of "personas", I think the question is basically okay now. It as at least clear where the problem is: the sentence quoted by Nigel at the top of his answer.

@curiousdannii -  Us being human is a characterization of our nature, it is part of our identity, but it is not our full identity. The creeds/doctrines I quoted indicate no distinction in full identity possible for God the Father/Son/HS.

"The creeds/doctrines I quoted indicate no distinction in full identity possible for God the Father/Son/HS." The creeds don't use "identity" language, but I don't think anything in them precludes distinctions in identity. And of course the relational roles of father, son, and spirit would to most people suggest distinct identities.

Isn't the reference to relational roles drifting into modalism? The creed and doctrine quoted describe in detail what (the trinitarian) God IS - the very definition of God's IDENTITY is what they describe, which includes the eminent subsistences of the "indivisible" and "uncompounded" Godhead! I might add a quote from a Lutheran/protestant perspective as well which re-affirms this.

While Trinitarians often dislike "role" as a term too, I think "relational roles" is okay, because it stresses the inherent relationality of it. Modalism has no true relations within the godhead, whereas Trinitarianism/Binitarianism do.

@curiousdannii why are you so dug in on this particular question?  It’s nice to see a mod doing their job but I think yiu are spending too much time trying to micro manage a perfectly answerable question.

@Kris As I'm sure you've experienced before, asking questions of a denomination about something they don't believe or teach just isn't fair to anyone. And if you're only looking at the question in its current form then you're seeing it in its much improved state.

I have flagged this for Moderator intervention as answers have been nullified by the OP fundamentally changing the question.

Trinitarians have neither the desire nor the need to 'reconcile' John 5:31 with the question since Trinitarians do not accept what is being stated. The OP has misunderstood Trinitarian dcotrine and is juggling with words 'identity' and now 'being'. It is all clear when one uses the word 'person' (as I have indicated).

@NigelJ How have I “fundamentally changed the question”? From the start I’ve asked for a reconciling response from “Trinitarians” - not Modalists nor Tritheists (which Trinitarians would agree are not Trinitarians). All other changes were mostly triggered by mod comments and demands - a mod actually removed half of my initial statement without my agreement, but I didn’t complain. If I look back I actually wonder as to whether any change was needed at all, as I only had to “correct” one very small thing in relation to something the mod has already removed from the OP.

The question now makes no sense. Trinitarians do not have to reconcile anything about the text quoted. Three persons may testify of one another. The problem lies with the misunderstanding of the questioner who equates 'identity' and 'being' to mean 'nature'. Rather than accepting that Trinitarianism sees three Persons share one divine nature.

@NigelJ - so are the trinitarian Athanasian creed, the official doctrine of Circumincission, and the trinitarian renowned Theologian scholar that I quoted wrong? If so how? I did not make the definition. If the Father, Son and HS share the divine nature, just as you, me and the mod share the human nature - if that is the Trinity, I would object it differently. It just oddly sounds like what a true Trinitarian would consider as “heretical Tritheism”.

I cannot assist you with the entire spectrum of theological thought and the various attempts (many of them failed attempts) to convey in Latin and English what is clearly made known, in very simple language, in the Greek scripture. No, it is not the same as you and I sharing human nature. Of course not. God is Spirit. Not flesh and blood. These concepts are not difficult to those who know the indwelling of God the Holy Spirit within their own spirit, through regeneration. Not at all difficult. A presence within, closer than one's own breath.

@JsWitness please take a look at the comment policy on meta.  In my opinion, your comments on the answers are discussion starters, not simple requests for clarification.  The expectation on this site is that if you don't like an answer, you downvote and move on.  Only comment if you don't understand something someone says, if the answer is lacking in your option, just wait until you get a better answer.

@JsWitness for instance, if you get what you perceive as a modalist or tritheist answer, just downvote.  It's unacceptable to set up a catch-22 question here and try to trap people.  If you want to start up "religiousgotchas.stackexchange.com" there's always area51

Note that Dolezal's quote is talking about the attributes of God. The persons of the Trinity are not attributes of God.

@curiousdannii - isn’t one of His attributes that He is ONE (Deuteronomy 6:4) - Doesn’t that imply that the different person’s inseparable unity with each other is absolute and “ontologically identical” with God’s very existence. Each person is equally identified as GOD, “yet there are not three Gods, but ONE God”.  I’m Father, Son, and Husband - all three “persons” or roles are part of my ONE ontological identity. In court  I’m incapable to give multiple witnesses as I cannot separate my role/person from my identity/nature/existence.

@JsWitness That's a great argument against modalism!

@JsWitness check it out: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/96011/60347

@curiousdannii - Thank you. And as my roles/characteristics are inseparable from my identity/nature/existence - which according to trinitarian creed and doctrine is the same with the Trinity - my witness, whether as Son or Father or Husband cannot be separated. Separating it would mean to separate my existence from my characteristics, in which case I’m no longer fully me but something or someone else. According to the attribute of immutability of God, that is impossible. Hence why I think Jesus’ words about 2 separate witnesses in himself and the Father are irreconcilable with the Trinity.

This whole discussion was very insightful - thank you to all that had to put up with me - I put many of the insights gained in this discussion in an answer here if anyone is interested: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/100964/65225

The law regarding witnesses is for men, given to men by God, because the hearts of men are deceitful and wicked:  Corroboration is needed in order for human testimony to even begin to be trustworthy.  This law is for protection against false accusation and the establishment of iniquity.
As such it does not apply to God, in whom there is no iniquity.  Therefore, when God declares

I am the LORD, and there is no other; there is no God but Me. - Isaiah 45:5

his testimony remains true even though He speaks alone and of Himself.  The Law does not apply to God:  It is given because of human iniquity.
So, when Jesus says, at John 18:14

Though I bear record of myself, yet my record is true: for I know whence I came, and whither I go; but ye cannot tell whence I come, and whither I go.

He is separating Himself, in this statement, from the application of this law based upon a knowledge that his audience does not possess.  What is that knowledge?  Jesus knows where He came from and his accusers do not.
He appeals to His testimony of Himself, the Father's testimony about Him, and the works that God has given Him to do all as a matter of condescension so that some might believe that He is the Christ, the Son of the Living God.  But, according to the law, there is no need for Jesus and the Father to be ontologically distinct because the law does not apply to God nor to sinless humanity.  One testimony is sufficient.
That is why Jesus remarks "it is also written in your law" (not our law) and why the remainder of the passage in John 8 finishes the way it does:

It is also written in your law, that the testimony of two men is true. I am one that bear witness of myself, and the Father that sent me beareth witness of me. Then said they unto him, Where is thy Father? Jesus answered, Ye neither know me, nor my Father: if ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also. - John 8:17-19

If they had accepted the testimony of the Son given by the Father (who needs no corroboration) they would have had no need of further testimony.  As it stands, demanding corroborative testimony from the Son is no different from demanding corroborative testimony from the Father.

Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that dwelleth in me, he doeth the works. - John 14:10

When Jesus testifies of Himself it is the Father that dwells in Him that is speaking.  The whole thing is a matter of disbelieving the Father.

If I may, I will offer another answer from a different angle.
God has perfect integrity.  That is to say, God never does or says anything that in any way contradicts or opposes who and what God is.  God is always perfectly represented in word and deed.
God is infinite in His attributes and therefore the perfection of His integrity is infinite such that who He is (Father), what He thinks and says (Logos/Son), and His acts/means of acting (Spirit) never lose ontological sameness.  God is always infinitely perfectly represented in thought, word, and deed.
God is also eternal and so is always eternally infinitely perfectly represented in thought, word, and deed. We cannot see God (who He is) and so it is by Word and Deed that the Father is revealed.  His Word was made flesh to manifest His Deeds, thus revealing Himself.  "If you have seen me you have seen the Father".  And again, "You neither know me, nor my Father; if you had known me you should have known my Father also".  And again, "The Father that dwelleth in me, He doeth the works".
There is both a distinction and an inseparability of the two:  I and the Father are one.
God the Father sends forth His word (Logos/Son) and that Word accomplishes that for which it was sent.  The Word is distinct from the Father as being sent from Him and yet not other than God as eternally, infinitely, perfectly representing God.
If God may claim personhood (Father) then the Word/Logos, which is not other than God, also may claim personhood (Son).  This Word/Logos, this Son, was made flesh and anointed with the Spirit (the deeds and the means) to reveal God the Father.
Jesus offers all three as testimony:  What He says of Himself, what the Father says of Him, and the works He does by the Spirit.  They are three witnesses; three eternal, infinite, perfect witnesses distinct from one another in eternally, infinitely, perfectly representing one eternal, infinite, and perfect God.


Because if they are ONE in essence, nature, power, action, and will, and thus cannot say, act, and will differently from each other . . . . . [sic, OP above]

This is incorrect.
That Divine Persons share one divine nature, being three separate individual persons, and that they do so in a perfection of love, means that no one will contradict the will of another. The actions of one will not damage another, nor frustrate the purposes of another. For 'God Love is' (literal, expressing an equivalence).
But that none desires to act in contradiction does not indicate the absence of independent will, nor the absence of independence of action. Not at all.
Therefore the premise that none can act as witness to another is a false premise.
For love determines that if a true witness is called for, then such a witness will be testified, independently and willingly.
To pretend that a loving unity of purpose obviates the ability to independently testify, truthfully and righteously, is false.

Nor is this a legal matter.

... the "witness" they are bearing about each other is legally unacceptable by the Judaic Law that God himself established! [sic, OP above]

The purposes and activities of Deity soar far, far above legal premise and exactitude. God's ultimate purpose is 'to bring many sons to glory' through a redemption which in no way can be required by law, be exacted by law or be provided by law.
The witness that Divine Persons testify of one another is within a divine perfection of absolute love, in glorious and true light, soaring far, far, above anything that law could reach to or accomplish.

But now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, being witnessed by the law and the prophets; Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all them that believe.[Romans 3:21 KJV]


This is what you stated Js Witness in your conclusion.
"Legally speaking you cannot separate the witness from the being giving the witness. If the three persons of the Trinity are ONE in essence, nature, power, action, and will, and thus cannot say, act, and will differently from each other, then we cannot get three separate, distinct or independent testimonies from it, but only one. For there is no variation in point of view or dependence, that would warrant it to be accepted as a separate independent witness. Jesus' own words would apply that "if I testify about myself [my identity], my testimony is not true".
It would mean that if any person of the God-Head, testifies about any other person of the God-Head or about the God-Head itself, according to the judicial Law established by God/YHWH himself, this testimony alone would not be acceptable to Jewish judges abiding to that Law."
Your first mistake in your statement is when you said, "Jesus' own words would apply that "if I testify about myself [my identity], my testimony is not true"." No, the "words" of Jesus would not be true, not His identity of who He is.
Now, remember are discussions regarding the "angel of the Lord" in the OT who is identified as the messenger of God. Legally speaking he was a "distinct person" from God and at Genesis 22:15-16 said, "Then the angel of the Lord called out to Abraham a second time from heaven, vs16, "AND SAID, BY MYSELF I HAVE SWORN DECLARES THE LORD, because you have done this thing, and have not withheld you son, your only son.
You also said this: "Even if you say that God the Father, God the Son, God the Holy Spirit are different persons of the God-Head, it would still be legally unacceptable due to the very nature of God's subsistence according to the Trinity dogma: The three persons are one and the same being: GOD.
First of all the Godhead is not three "different" persons, they are three "distinct" persons who share the same nature. It's no different that human beings having the same nature but yet humans are distinct persons. Your not the person of your father or mother. Moreover, as distinct persons you would be giving a "separate" testimony as a witness.
You also said: "Jesus says "in your own Law it is written that the testimony of two witnesses is true". He clearly follows that Law as well in John 5:31-37 in regards to the legality of his witness. Who are the two witnesses Jesus mentions in John 8:17,18? Himself and the Father!"
So, how is this any different from what God said at Hebrews 6:13-18 regarding the angel of the Lord being a distinct witness/person from His Father? "For when God made the promise to Abraham, since He could not swear by no one greater, He swore BY HIMSELF, vs14, "saying, "I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you.
Let me say in conclusion the problem (as I see it) has to do with the definition of words and their meaning. When we speak of a living, rational being we are usually speaking of all that a particular concrete existence is, person + nature, not person in distinction of nature. For example, Gods nature distinguishes Him from all that is not God. Human nature distinguishes humans from all that is not human. Ask yourself this question? Why did Jesus Christ on numerous occasions identify Himself as (1) The Son of God, and (2) The Son of Man?

Britannica Dictionary says “Distinct means "different in a way that you can see, hear, smell, feel, etc." or "noticeably different." Different means "not of the same kind" or "partly or totally unlike." Your response resorts to Tritheism to force a reconciliation. Tritheists think that the common nature of the Trinity is an abstraction; so that, while the three persons are consubstantial, they are distinct in their properties. This view was condemned as tritheism at the Third Council of Constantinople in 680–81. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritheism

Distinct means "different in a way that you can see, hear, smell, feel, etc." or "noticeably different." Different means "not of the same kind" or "partly or totally unlike." Also consider the following: Distinct and Different are nuances of the same notion of difference. Distinct refers to a sharper difference, something that is very noticeable, which stands out. Distinction serves to delineate the order of existence among members of the Trinity. Each have the same nature and are distinct persons with the same kind of nature, which is "Deity" or "God." This is "NOT" tritheism.

From the definition of Britannica Dictionary "Distinct" means "less" difference than "Different". I think your right, "distinct" is better, but it denotes more similarity in the persons than "different" does. "Order of existence"? Does that mean one is higher than the other, or existed before the other? "Members" denotes that the Trinity is a "group". A group of persons "with the same kind of nature". Which would be three Gods (just as we are two Humans). This is Tritheism. Three persons but one personality, would that be correct?

No, the order of existence serves to delineate the persons of the Godhead. The Father is commonly said to be the first person of the Godhead, followed by the Son and then the Holy Spirit. It does not mean one is higher in nature since all three persons share the same nature. We as human beings share the same nature, we all are distinct persons. Your  a distinct person from your father and mother. Jesus is the Son of His Father which means He is the same nature as His Father. His mother who bore Jesus is human, therefore Jesus had two natures, human and deity.  Hence, Son of God and Son of man

I don't deny that Jesus has the same divine nature than his Father, just as we both share the same human nature.   That makes us 2 separate Humans - just as the Son and the Father are two separate Gods - add the Holy Spirit to the equation and you have Tritheism. What about this: "Each person is equally identified as GOD, “yet there are not three Gods, but ONE God”. I’m Father, Son, and Husband - all three “persons” or roles are part of my ONE ontological identity. Doesn't this fit the Trinity doctrine better? This implies that God has a personality - but has He? What do you think?

You said: "I don't deny that Jesus has the same divine nature than his Father, just as we both share the same human nature." You also said, " I’m Father, Son, and Husband - all three “persons” Now think for a second about what your saying? This is classic "Modalism." Your comparing an ontological being to roles which is an invalid comparison. If a person never gets married then he is not considered a husband, which is a role. Your nature is always with you and it never changes. Even today, certain groups are saying, "I know my baby was born a boy, but I say it's a girl. How sick is that?
